# multiprocessing a function that returns list in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Given this example:

I want to distribute the calculation over a list (map)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def fun(elem):
    lis = []
    for i in range(0,elem):
        lis.append(i)
    return lis

p = Pool(3)

p.map(fun, [2,3,4])
```

How can I make something like this work?

Comment: What's not working right now?

Comment: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function fun at 0x7fb8fea2c9d8>: attribute lookup fun on __ main __ failed

Comment: Your code runs for me without any changes (Python 3.7.9). If I wrap the call to `p.map` in a `print` statement, the output is `[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]`, as you would expect.

Comment: Uh.. I had the error above

Comment: I understand. But if I dump your code into a file and run it, I don't get any errors. That's why I mentioned the version of Python I'm using for starters, so that you can let us know if your environment differs in some significant way.

Comment: The code does work. See this link: https://repl.it/repls/RewardingBravePerl

Comment: I see. Maybe something wrong with my env. I will have a look

Comment: Assuming you're running on Windows or macOS (and good practice even if not), or explicitly opted in to `spawn` or `forkserver` launch methods, make sure you've got a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard controlling creation of the `Pool` and its use; otherwise, you'll have some interesting issues with spawning the worker tasks. This is mentioned in [the `multiprocessing` docs' Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).